# Counting threads within a console application c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reference, backgroundworker

I am currently porting code from a WPF application to a Console app. In the wpf viewmodel I stored an integer variable (int NumberOfThreads) and I am able to manipulate it by incrementing when the threads are created, and decrementing when the RunWorkerCompleted method is called. This is a little harder in a Console app as I know that declaring a public static variable that mimics a global variable is a big no.

I also need to pass a filename, a log, and a bool that signifies if there is errors in the log, to the DoWork, along with the number of threads integer. This is what I have so far:

```
 private static void ProcessFile(string file, CwiLogger log, ref int numberOfThreads, bool hasErrors)
        {
            Interlocked.Increment(ref numberOfThreads);
            var processFileBackgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
            processFileBackgroundWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(processFileBackgroundWorker_DoWork);
            processFileBackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler
                    (processFileBackgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted);
            var processFileTuple = new Tuple<string, CwiLogger, int, bool>(file, log, numberOfThreads, hasErrors);
            processFileBackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync(processFileTuple);
        }
```

this way i figure i can unpack the tuple in the DoWork function. and then pass a different tuple to RunWorkerCompleted method.

However I am assuming that this is not passing them by reference to the DoWork function, and that when i pass them into e.Results, it will also be by value and not reference. So when i decrement in RunWorkerCompleted, it will be decrementing a copy.

Comment: Have you thought about using the TPL and collecting all the work into a `List<Task>`?

Comment: Forgive my ignorance as I am fairly new to this, but I don't see how this would solve my issue.

Comment: You can't pack a `ref` value into a tuple, and dealing with `ref` is a headache in general (delegates don't like them either). Create a new `ThreadCounter` class that wraps the count and pass that instead, or (if you don't actually need to change it from client code) a `Func<int>` that yields the value on demand (by getting it from some shared field). Note, however, that you're jumping through a lot of hoops to avoid what is still a global, just one that's slightly better encapsulated than most. It doesn't really add much.

Comment: @JacobAlley if you have time take a look at the MSDN TPL page (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717(v=vs.110).aspx). Basically it abstracts the use of `Thread` to what are called `Task`. It makes it very easy to do asynchronous work and handle what happens before and after the work. Try to find a tutorial and then make an analogy between the tutorial and you're application. `Task` is basically the replacement for `BackgroundWorker`.

Comment: thanks, yes this was definitely helpful and a lot more intuitive